# javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 534-5.7.14 while I try to send email from Jenkins job with java

Tags: java, jenkins, gmail

I successfully send email with java code from local, but when I try to send it with Jenkins Job I get the error:

```
> experimental > exp > tests.api.git.GitLabApiTest > testMessage
> STANDARD_ERROR
>     javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbu
>     534-5.7.14 bDIKUG2suNRjNmMKxowMLzUoGAHcRUPK_YDF06eQ6ijzc74BASWcufrFLABVjcFLwQ1Wz
>     534-5.7.14 xCJOo2QkWjY0Jq1226hjIB7vF_cK19R5EjW-cX4V6SBCSf_TC41Etylx9gI5r8AJ>
>     534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and then try again.
```

Code:

```java
public static void sendMessage(String from, String fromPass, String to, String subject, String body) {
        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        props.put("mail.smtp.user", from);
        props.put("mail.smtp.password", fromPass);
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

        session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
        try{
            MimeMessage mimeMessage = new MimeMessage(session);
            mimeMessage.setFrom(from);
            InternetAddress toAddress = new InternetAddress(to);
            mimeMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress);
            mimeMessage.setSubject(subject);
            mimeMessage.setText(body);
            Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
            transport.connect(host, from, fromPass);
            transport.sendMessage(mimeMessage, mimeMessage.getAllRecipients());
            transport.close();
        } catch (MessagingException mse) {
            mse.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            disconnect();
        }
    }
```

Jenkins settings:

[image]

- I can read an email, but not sending